# Replace the text of TH elements of a Table with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a page in wordpress and a plugin creates a table, but I want to change the text of the "th"

My problem is that I cannot access the code and I would like to do it with javascript but I have not been able to do it, because the "th" do not have id.

this is a part of the table:

```
<p id="search-table">
<table id="elc_search-table">
<thead><tr style="vertical-align: baseline;">
                    
<th>First Name</th>
<th>Last Name</th>
<th>Course or Quiz Title</th>
<th>Completion Date</th>

</tr>
</thead>
```

I am trying to change like that

```
<th>Nombre</th>
<th>Apellido</th>
<th>Curso o Quiz</th>
<th>Fecha de Terminación</th>
```

Comment: _"I cannot access the code"_ or you cannot find it?

Comment: Can you update your HTML file

Answer (score 2):

Add this script in your Javascript file to change the header:

```
const tr1 = document.querySelector('#elc_search-table thead tr:first-child');
const htmlTemplate = `
<th>Nombre</th>
<th>Apellido</th>
<th>Curso o Quiz</th>
<th>Fecha de Terminación</th>`;

tr1.innerHTML = htmlTemplate;
```

And this will replace the content within your `thead`.

Comment: Whoever has downvoted , Kindly give your justification. Thanks

Comment: not my downvote - `.innerHTML` is not rec-emended to be used. Consider using something else. Read more about `innerHTML` on MDN.

Comment: Even I know, but appendChild() doesn't work for htmlTemplates. Plus no one says never use innerHTML. In case we have to replace HTML completely with new HTML, do you have any suggestion which is precise.

Comment: Read more on Javascript MDN what else can be used. You will know why not `innerHTML` and what else can be used.

Comment: This answer is NOT efficient as well. this will FAIL if there is more then ONE `table` on the OP page. Your answer will change all the `th` on the same page.

Comment: That is surely not a problem I can use table's id in my selector. We really respect your Research. But for small problem like this It hardly matters whether we use appendChild() or innerHTML.

Comment: Edit your answer then and fix it by doing your own research. I am just trying to hightlight the issues you have in your current asnwer.

Comment: That's already done...And I myself am a Front End Web Developer with 3 years of experience now :) I really appreciate your suggestions...

Answer (score 0):

You can select it using tag like `getElementsByTagName` or by ccs selector like `querySelectorAll` both returns in array so you have to index on them to give them different value

```js
th = document.getElementsByTagName('th')[0].innerHTML = 'Nombre';
th = document.getElementsByTagName('th')[1].innerHTML = 'Apellido';
th = document.getElementsByTagName('th')[2].innerHTML = 'Curso o Quiz';
th = document.getElementsByTagName('th')[3].innerHTML = 'Fecha de Terminación';
```

```html
<p id="search-table">
  <table id="elc_search-table">
    <thead>
      <tr style="vertical-align: baseline;">

        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Course or Quiz Title</th>
        <th>Completion Date</th>

      </tr>
    </thead>
```

Comment: I also don't understand, what is going on. I also tried to answer using using html-template. Someone downvoted. I now deleted my answer. Really this is not good. Who does this and why?

Comment: `.innerHTML` is not rec-emended to be used. Consider using something else.

Comment: I don't know @ImranRafiqRather but shouldn't delete an answer that's not good idea

Comment: Have undeleted. Thanks for your advice @Gad

Comment: From the MDN => Warning: If your project is one that will undergo any form of security review, using innerHTML most likely will result in your code being rejected. For example, if you use innerHTML in a browser extension and submit the extension to addons.mozilla.org, it will not pass the automated review process.

Comment: What should be better to use? @AlwaysHelping

Comment: This answer is NOT efficient as well. this will FAIL if there is more then ONE `table` on the OP page. Your answer will change all the `th` on the same page.

Comment: @Gad use `.textContent()` instead of `innerHTML`

Answer (score 0):

`jQuery` would solve your problems what you are worrying now.

```
jQuery('#question-header th')[0] = 'Nombre';
jQuery('#question-header th')[1] = 'Apellido';
jQuery('#question-header th')[2] = 'Curso o Quiz';
jQuery('#question-header th')[3] = 'Fecha de Terminación';
```